# SQL SERVER. TSQL. Execute one my procedure after all other triggers and all other procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How to execute one my procedure after all triggers and procedures already in the database?

I have a big database, with many many tables, with many many columns.

This database is not created by me.

I need to call a my own procedure at the end of all triggers and procedures already existent in database.

For example: when I made an insert there are many triggers and procedures automatically started by database.

At the end of each trigger and procedure, I need to call one procedure that I wrote.

How to do?

UPDATE:

Or at least can I know which is the last trigger in the database? So then I can enter there the procedure?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is somehow unclear.

Comment: You would need to manually add the `exec` for your procedure into every other procedure and trigger. This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Or at least can I know which is the last trigger in the database? So then I can enter there the procedure?

Comment: We might do better if you can tell us what *task* this "must be called last" procedure is going to perform. Maybe there's a better way to get that job done that doesn't involve triggers at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last trigger using the below query

```
select sys.tables.name,sys.triggers.name,sys.trigger_events.type
,sys.trigger_events.type_desc, is_first,is_last
,sys.triggers.create_date,sys.triggers.modify_date
from sys.triggers inner join sys.trigger_events
on sys.trigger_events.object_id = sys.triggers.object_id
inner join sys.tables on sys.tables.object_id = sys.triggers.parent_id
WHERE is_Last=1
order by modify_date
```

if none of the triggers have is_last=1 then that means the trigger execution order is not set. To set trigger execution order yourself you can use the below query

```
EXEC sp_settriggerorder 
@triggername= 'Sales.uSalesOrderHeader', 
@order='Last', 
@stmttype = 'UPDATE';
```